# how can I create a temporary table in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, temp-tables

I have the tables: Suscriptions, Suscription_Book, Books

I want to update the Suscription_stock when I edit the stock of a Book from a Suscription

The new Suscription_stock will be the Lowest stock of its books

I'm creating a trigger in the Books table to update the Suscriptions when I edit a book.

I'm creating in the trigger a temporary table to save the "lowest stock" of the books in each suscription where I find the book I'm editing, and then I update the suscriptions.

But Mysql dont let me create a temporary table in the trigger, I'm trying create the temporary table in a stored procedure but I get this error: can't reopen table 'lowestStock'

this is the query:

```
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

drop table if exists lowestStock;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lowestStock select d.Susc_id, min(b.Prod_stock) as min
     from Suscription_Book d inner join v_books b on b.Prod_id=d.Book_id
where d.Susc_id in (select Susc_id from Suscription_Book where Book_id=new.Book_id)
group by d.Susc_id;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lowestStock INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
    update Suscriptions
        set Prod_stock = (select min from lowestStock Limit i,1)
        where Prod_id = (select Susc_id from lowestStock Limit i,1);
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

drop table if exists lowestStock ;
```

Comment: it is very rarely that one needs to loop through a queryset and do an update one by one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Triggers will allow you to create temporary tables but they won't allow you to drop them either within the trigger or if you call a procedure and you are not allowed for create a prepared statement.

Comment: How about a cursor instead of a temporary table?